# Import android gradle project when building sayes not found sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

Import android gradle project problem when building says not found SDK
in eclipse luna

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your Gradle properties. There must be an option to configure the SDK path because it's searching for it in a different location.

Comment: no place found to add SDK to gradle config

my android SDK configuration is fine the problem just in gradle when importing a project